# How to Pass Parameters from MVC controller to Javascript and get Result?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have written a function in javascript which take 10 parameters as input and make some calculations on them and then return answer. 
I am taking input from html page and returning result back to it. 
Now i want to make API for it which takes input and directly call javascript function and return results. 
I am using ASP .net MVC for this purpose as I am good in MVC development, but I am little bit confused that how can  I call js function directly from MVC controller and get results there.
Can any one please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {  // Calling this function on button click
    var a = 's';
    var b = 'Small';
    var c ='55';
    var  d ='88';

    getOutput(a,b,c,d);  // My javascript function which make calculations and return results
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, use return JavaScript("myFunction()"); and the Javascript should be referenced by the view you are using.

Comment: thanks, let me try it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the API to calculate whatever you are calculating, and only returning the answer to you. You could use AJAX for that. Or I might not understand your question good enough. In that case please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your response , actually issue is that that calculation javascript is function is written by some one else and Client ask me to just make its API, as calculation script has too much code so it will take time , so thats why i just want to use this javascript function directly from MVC controller.

Comment: But what do you want to do with the API?

Comment: Client will call this api in his Website

Comment: To retrieve/store data? Because you could just use a ajax call to get the data, en on retrieved run a javascript function.